# Discord.py sends argument "weird"

Tags: python, arrays, discord, discord.py

So, I  am making a discord music bot and when the person searches something it plays the music, and it uses the valuable **arg** for that so for example: *?play christmas song* but altough it does play the music correctly it sends this message: *Now playing:* **('christmas', 'song')** It's like it cuts the 2 words and puts them both in like a sort of list?

This is my code:

```
@commands.command()
  async def play(self, ctx, *arg):
    
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("Join a voice channel")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    try:
      requests.get("" + str(arg))
    except: arg = " " + str(arg)
    else: arg = "" + str(arg)
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)
      if 'entries' in info:
        video = info['entries'][0]
      else:
        video = info
      url2 = video['formats'][0]['url']
      print(video)
      video_url = video['url']
      print(video_url)
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      await ctx.send("Now playing: **" + str(arg) + "**")
      vc.play(source)
```

Comment: `*arg` makes it a _tuple_ of the positional arguments.

Comment: The string representation of a tuple will have the parentheses and comma. If you want to join them together, do `' '.join(arg)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `async def play(self, ctx, *arg):` do `async def play(self, ctx, *, arg):` by making a keyword argument, it tells discord.py to consume all of the arguments passed to that single argument

so a command invoked as `{prefix}play hello from adelle`, in your command, your `arg` will be `hello from adelle`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're just print what you receive as parameter, you need to decouple the **arg** as like this:

```
await ctx.send("Now playing: **" + *arg + "**")
```

or

```
await ctx.send("Now playing: **" + ' '.join(arg) + "**")
```